# Помогите разобраться со Scanner в Java

Tags: java, строки, scanner

```
public class Exercise58 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a Sentence: ");
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String upper_case_line = "";
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        while(lineScan.hasNext()) {
            String word = lineScan.next();
            upper_case_line += Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1) + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(upper_case_line.trim());
    }
}
```

что обозначает строка `Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная строка

```
Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
```

это создание объекта класса **Scanner**. У класса **Scanner** есть несколько **конструкторов**. Данный **конструктор** получает на вход **строку** в которой и производится поиск **токенов**.

Так как **разделитель** не указан, то используется разделитель по умолчанию - это любой символ (Character) для которого результат вызова `Character.isWhitespace` равен **true**.

В вашем случае **строка** будет разделена на **токены** из **символов** разделенных **пробелами**.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = in.nextLine(); //считывает всю введенную строку 
nextLine(): считывает всю введенную строку 
while(lineScan.hasNext() )//до тех пор пока не будет введено слово
```

Так как `line` у вас является строкой, то он получит всю введенную строку и после будет цикл, который повторяется до тех пор пока в строке не будет найдено слово

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
```

т.к. line строка, то используется конструктор:

```
public Scanner(String source) 
Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string. 
Parameters: source - A string to scan
```

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)